# Loose color names in randomColor.js

Tags: javascript

I'm using this lovely library for color randomization. It allows you to specify the type of colors you would like to use based on hsl value ranges. (light, dark, bright)

```
randomColor({ luminosity: 'light', hue: 'blue' });
```

[randomColor.js](https://github.com/davidmerfield/randomColor)

[Demo Site](https://randomcolor.llllll.li/)

Does anyone know of a way to reverse engineer this? I would like it to return a random color and a loose description of the color. (light blue, dark green, bright red, luminosity + hue range)

I feel like there should be a way to do this, but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and find a small demonstrative example code to put directly in your question, rather than linking to a large file. If you can set up your attempted answer, it will be easier to understand (even just an empty method with the inputs and outputs described).

Answer (score 0):

The javascript library [Tiny Color](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) can help you do color conversions and will even tell you if a color is light or dark. Take a look at the [Wikipedia HSL entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and you'll see how you can associate a hue value with a color name.